# Computing $P\left [ X+Y > \frac{1}{2}\right ]$ - Confusion on setting up the integration bounds

Tags: calculus, probability

I want to compute $P\left [ X+Y > \frac{1}{2}\right ]$ for $f(x,y) = 1I(0<x<2)I(0<y<1-\frac{x}{2})$.

What is confusing me is how to handle the fact that we wish to integrate over the triangle for which $f(x,y)=1$ s.t. $X > \frac{1}{2} - Y$.

If the restriction were $x>y$ then I know that anything below the line $y=x$ satisfies $x>y$, but for $x> \frac{1}{2} - y$, I am unsure.

After we take out the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (0,\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2},0)$, how can do explicit integration on the remaining shape? I do not know how to split the shape up.

I think it may be: $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1 - \frac{x}{2}} 1 dy dx  + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2} \int_{0}^{1 - \frac{x}{2}} 1 dy dx$.

Comment: Have you tried sketching the region where $f(x,y)=1$ and the region where $X+Y>\frac12$ on a graph? You should find that you can do the problem geometrically without any (explicit) integration.

Comment: @DanRobertson I just wrote my geometric idea in my post. Is what I said correct?

Comment: We are not cutting out a small square, we are cutting out a small triangle, area $1/8$.  What's left is $\dots$, no integration.

Comment: Oh, of course it is a triangle: 1/2  - x is a line. Since $f(x,y)=1$, then we ca n solve the problem without integration. So we can compute the area of the whole triangle $-$ the area of the triangle we are taking out ($\frac{1}{8}$).  Suppose I did want to compute the triangle (where we take out the triangle of $1/8$) with integration. How would we? It is not a "nice" shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in a sketch:[image: sketch of solution]

Sadly the left hand side has been cut off. The values read (top to bottom) 1, $\frac12,$ 0.

It should be simple enough to find the area of the intersection, $A$. If you feel the need to integrate, it can be done as:

$$A=\int_0^2\int_0^{1-\frac x2} f(x,y) \mathrm d y\mathrm dx - \int_0^{\frac12}\int_0^{\frac12-x} f(x,y) \mathrm d y\mathrm dx.$$

(Note that $f(x,y)\equiv 1$ in both integrands)

Comment: Dan, right,  understand the sketch (see comments). I am struggling on how to explicitly integrate the region we want. I think it may be: $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1 - \frac{x}{2}} 1 dy dx  + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2} \int_{0}^{1 - \frac{x}{2}} 1 dy dx$.

Comment: Is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @ProtInk, Yes your answer is incorrect. You have the triangle to the left of the line $x=\frac12$ and the triangle above the line $y=\frac12.$ Do you see which region is missing?

Comment: Ah yes, here we go I think: http://mathb.in/45046

Comment: @Protink, That integral is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Tip:** If resolving the bounds ever seems hard, try using complements as it *may* be easier.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X+Y>\tfrac 1 2) 
& = 1 - \mathsf P(X+Y\leq \tfrac 1 2)
\\[1ex] & = 1- \iint_{0<x<\min(2,1/2-y), 0< y\leq \min( 1/2-x, 1-x/2)} 1\operatorname d (x,y)
\\[1ex] & = 1-\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{\min(1/2-x,1-x/2)} 1\operatorname dy\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = 1 - \int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{1/2-x} 1\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & \ddots
\end{align}$$